# How to fix: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '... .json' (Python, Google)

Tags: python, org.json

I'm trying to connect python and google (created a key, enabled google sheets and google drive), gave an access to one of my google sheets.

```
import gspread
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

my_mail='tatiana@gmail.com'


credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('able-d392d507369d.json', scope)
gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

It stopped at

```
'ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('able-d392d507369d.json', scope)'
```

With

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'able-d392d507369d.json'
```

Please, if you know how to fix that, help me!

Comment: Try to use an absolute path because relative paths may not point to the expected location.

Comment: Are you 1000% percent certain that "able-d392d507369d.json" exists? Check filenames closely! If you're certain an absolute path is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how create an absolute path here?

Comment: Put the complete path i.e. `/users/user/documents/mycode/json/able-d392d507369d.json`.